# Sentry.js file prevents replit.com from properly compiling

Tags: javascript, replit

I am currently creating a certain website on replit.com, and during the process, I have found that compilation errors were arising. Replit.com would try to compile, but would be stuck in the compiling process and won't get out of it. I eventually found the problem to be a sentry.js file, and I can't seem to see why its corrupting the compilation process. Can you provide me with advice on this situation, as it would be very helpful.

I unfortenently can't send my entire code because it would be too large, and I can't pin point the problem inside the code.